# WPF Event to capture newly added controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, controls

We use the ContentControl and other containers stuff in WPF. I need the notification with the new child control is added to the container. What is the best way to get the newly created control within parent?

Answer (score 3):

The *ContentControl* only contains a single child which is attached via the *ContentControl.Content* property. You can hook the *ContentControl.OnContentChanged* to discover when the value of this property is updated.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is to derive from those control and override the methods that report the changes you are interested in.  For example derive from `ContentControl` and implement `OnContentChanged`.  This approach may not appeal to you.

If you want to detect changes in the child or children of controls without deriving from them, you can observe that such changes will affect the layout and so you can hook the `LayoutUpdated` event.  The problem with this approach is that you need to keep track of the children that were previously added yourself by inspecting `Child` or `Children` looking for changes.  You also have to be careful not to hang onto references to former children lest you create a memory leak.  But it can be done.